# How to make a picker view dynamically in Xcode in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview, uipickerviewdatasource

I am newbie in iOS.I a trying to make picker view  in a navigation toolbar my dates are coming their sucessfully.I need to make a  Picker view which fills datasource with 2 names and on selection of it i need to return it in string so that I can apply a sql query on it.

I have already mentioned the method of picker view for making my dates come their.

The issue is that I need  picker views one which selects the date and other which shows 2 name For e.g 1)Emergency 2)Synergy11.I need to fill both in the picker view. Please let me know.

Comment: You're asking a rather complex, multipart question. I'd recommend starting by going through a couple tutorials. You'll easily find good ones by searching: https://www.google.com/search?q=objective+c+uipickerview+tutorial

Comment: if you want to use single pickerview for all at the same time then you need to provide number of component for pickerview is 3 and set data according to component